# Add an API Key to Http request in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, api

Below is a POST method that will generate an API Key

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $response = Http::post('ENDPOINT', [
        'Username' => 'ADMIN',
        'Password' => 'ADMIN',
        'Token' => 'TEF53...',
    ]);
```

And the next method (POST) will create new data and use the above response as an API Key

```
    $response2 = Http::withHeaders([
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ])->post('ENDPOINT', [
        'body' => [
            "DocKey" => 11223333355,
            ...
        ]
    ]);
    return json_decode($response2);
}
```

But in this case i am getting an error:

```
Message "Authorization has been denied for this request."
```

The reason is the API Key isn't provided in the previous POST method

where can i place the generated API Key from the first method in the second method?

---

More clarification:

When i test the second method ($response2) in Postman, I need to provide the generated API Key from the first method ($response) as shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOp1b.png

How can i add the above (Type API Key and its parameters)?

Comment: please provide more info what you are trying to achieve, there can be many ways to answer this. are you kicking off two requests from a client, what is the key for, ...?

Comment: The API you are accessing should provide information on where it expects the key. Usually it's an authorisation header so in the `withHeaders` part you'd also have something like `'Authorisation' => 'Bearer <token value>'`

Comment: So the "key" that you get back is "eyJ..."? And does this request with Postman work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like

```
$response2 = Http::withHeaders([
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'eyJ...', // provide apiKey here
])->post...
```

Comment: i tried this but using the variable of the first method and it didn't work because i didn't use "json_decode" so now its working, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$endpoint = 'ENDPOINT';
$payload = [
             'DocKey' => 11223333355,
             'more info' => goes here,
           ];

$response2 = Http::acceptJson()->withHeaders([
                'Authorization' => 'API key here'
            ])->post($endpoint, $payload)->json();

return $response2;
```